# Does Unicorn pick up database cleanup process and reserialize?

Tags: unicorn, serialization

While reading [**this**](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/3419/how-does-the-clean-up-databases-feature-work) thread, I investigated if "cleanup databases" will trigger serialization  process. I checked log files and nothing related to serialization is logged?

@Dmytro suggested that Sitecore never triggers serialization process.

Does that mean someone who is using Unicorn will get those orphan trees and items back in the next sync? Is it better to reserialize in unicorn.aspx every time we did a database cleanup?

Or does Unicorn pick up the database cleanup task and reserialize automatically?

Comment: I don't think Sitecore _ever_ triggers serialization automatically? So I suppose this question is actually about whether or not Unicorn will pick up database changes after you run a cleanup.

Comment: make sense. I will update the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I asked [a similar question](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/2594/unicorn-writing-to-disk-with-transparent-sync-off) a little while back, about the interop between Sitecore and Unicorn on disk files.

If you have `Transparent-Sync` on or have your `Unicorn.DataProvider.config` file configured, then there is a direct relation between Sitecore and the Unicorn serialization files on disk. If you update an item, in a part of Sitecore that is tracked, the changes will be written to disk. If you are not running `Transparent Sync` or have your `Unicorn.DataProvider.config` configured (in production scenario). When you run unicorn.aspx again, it move those items to the recycle bin, if they are new. And put them back, if they still exist on disk.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Cleanup databases triggers a cleanup of the SQL tables, not of content items' effective data. Serialized item state should be unaffected by a cleanup.